# Android app not saving in the database with Url

Tags: database, azure, xamarin, url, xamarin.android

I have this code for saving some content into an Azure Database, the fields that i have are

```
Name(string), Lastname(string), Date of birth(DateTime), Illnes(string), Email(string), Phone(int)
```

but when I try to save it it's basically not working, is throwing me the "Couldn't save data" message that I typed in a validation, idk if im doing something wrong

This is the code to send the information to the database

[image: Code]

Comment: Please put the code in the question body so people searching for help on a related problem can find the question more easily.

Comment: You need to determine what response code the server is sending and why.  Based on the information you posted there is no way for us to debug this for you